# Dozer Converter map String to String

Tags: java, jaxb, dozer

I am working with Dozer and it is mapping our JAXB objects that are coming from our WebService to business object that reside in the service layer of our application.  In some particular cases I need to map codes in String values to human readable description in String values.
Example:  "FLT" maps to "FLAT"  and "TRP" maps to "TRAP".  I have a lot of these type mappings.

I am implementing a custom Dozer Converter by inheriting the **DozerConverter** and implementing the two abstract methods  **convertTo**() and **convertFrom**().  Within these I wanted to map "FLT" to "FLAT" and "FLAT" to "FLT" respectively but unforunatly Dozer does not call the correct **convertTo**() or **convertFrom**() methods correctly.

Does anyone else have this problem and could point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the POJOs, you could treat these strings as enums. You would have to define enums for the webservice side and the business logic side, but I think it's a more elegant solution than using a converter or xmladapter.

Enum examples:

```
public enum ENUM_WS {
  @XmlEnumValue("TRP") TRAP,
  @XmlEnumValue("FLT") FLAT
}

public enum ENUM_BL {
  @XmlEnumValue("TRAP") TRAP,
  @XmlEnumValue("FLAT") FLAT
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could address this issue at the JAXB level.  To to this you could leverage an `XmlAdapter` that converted the XML string (i.e. FLT) to the object String (i.e. FLAT).

If you are generating your object model from an XML schema the following may help:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/xml-schema-to-java-generating.html